# How to get Access Token from gmail?

Tags: laravel-5, gmail-api, google-client

The Main issue I am facing here is as soon as I hit the sendmail api ( This API send mail using google email api ) it gives me error of `Undefined index: access_token`

I want to send email using GMAIL Email API in my Laravel Project. For that I had followed this github doc:https://github.com/dacastro4/laravel-gmail. I am successfully able to do setup it with my project. But then struck in above error. Below is my code:

```
        use Dacastro4\LaravelGmail\Services\Message\Mail;

        $mail = new Mail;
        $mail->to( 'TOMAIL', $name = "Tester" );
        $mail->from( 'MYMAIL', $name = "Own Tester" );
        $mail->subject( "Hello World" );
        $mail->message( "Google It Brother." );
        $mail->send();
```

Expected response is it should send the email to user using gmail api.

Comment: Send mail is not the same as the Gmail api.   You should check out the PHP quick start for the gmail api if you want to use that https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php  If you want to go though the smtp server then your going to have to send the login and password for the user https://artisansweb.net/sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-server-laravel/

Comment: I done this quickstart.php stuff in core php but I am unable to do this for laravel setup. Thats why I used that package but that giving me issue of access_token @DaImTo

Comment: You dont need an access token with the SMTP server. You need to send the login and password its two different things.  If you want to use the gmail api your going to have to find a larvel rapper for the gmail api.  https://github.com/dacastro4/laravel-gmail

Answer (score 0):

Try the following links:

https://artisansweb.net/sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-server-laravel/

Summary Notes:

Inside your Gmail account setting:

```
1. Allow Less Secure App Access
2. Create an app password
3. in your application configuration, provide the your gmail account's app password (not your gmail account password)
```

Comment: Thanks But  I need to use gmail api instead of this SMTP way.

Comment: The tutorial is about the Gmail's SMTP.